# Want to get html content of Microsoft Live Login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, https, windows-live, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have url:

> `https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=http%3a%2f%2fcorp.sts.microsoft.com&wctx=7b4cd04b-7dc2-4880-9f77-20c8c6ef64c4&wct=2013-03-11T06%3a54%3a42Z&whr=uri%3aWindowsLiveID.`

I want to get htmlcotent of this webpage as string. My Code Looks like this.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string html =  wc.DownloadString("url");
```

When I examine the content in `html` string I see an error message:

> Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser
>   either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked. To
>   find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, or to allow
>   scripts, see the browser's online help.

Comment: can i know for what reason you are scrapping the web page ?

Comment: Basically i want to crawl a Microsoft webpage which is Live Authenticated. So i am just stuggling get the webage html content.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `User-Agent` request header to some know browser which will trick the website into thinking that it supports javascript:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22";
    string html =  wc.DownloadString("https://www.microsoft.com/en-/itacademy/members/default.aspx");
}
```

Obviously if the site performs some javascript tasks they will not be executed and you cannot rely on them because the WebClient doesn't support that.

If on the other hand you are attempting to authenticate against Live ID, I would strongly recommend you using OAuth for that purpose. Here's the [`documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) which explains how to integrate this type of authentication with Live ID after you registered your application as a relying party.

Comment: Hey Darin Thanks for response. I have Integrated the Windows Live Javascript API to asp.net mvc3 and i am able to perform Authentication. But i am just struggling to get the webpage content. I tried setting Headers in the Request object But still the result is same which i mentioned above. I used httpwebrequest also.